# ie 9 shows different renders of the same html file

Tags: html, internet-explorer

My problem is this: I have two duplicates of an index.html page that render differently in IE 9, depending on if the file is on an exteral USB drive or the native harddisk drive! It is driving me nuts and the only difference is where the file is. The page is properly structured and has  a doctype 5 declaration. Chrome and Firefox have no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely explanation: In one case, it's running in **Standards Mode** because it's in the Internet Zone, and in the other it's running in **Compatibility View** because it's in the Local Computer zone.

There's likely a hidden alternate data stream ("Mark of the Web") on the file that's causing this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx